# how to refresh pinned row data in AG Grid Vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, ag-grid

I have some pinned bottom row in the grid. I want to update the cell after adding or deleting some rowData in the grid. Here is the code:

```
this.gridApi.pinnedBottomRowData = rowNode.setDataValue(date, dataToPush);
this.gridApi.updateRowData(event.rowIndex);
this.gridApi.refreshCells({
   rowNodes: [rowNode],
   columns: [date],
   force: true;
});
```

However, the grid cannot update the view of the row. Backend can work properly but frontend cannot. Is there any way to update the pinned row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I lost the code with `this.gridApi.setPinnedBottomRowData(this.pinnedBottomRowData);`
So, the pinned bottom row data did not have to data to show.